# how to make mvc 4 webgrid serial number continuous?

Tags: model-view-controller, webgrid

How to make the row number of the different pages continuous starting the first page up to the end page ??

creating continuous row number !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I had faced such problem but solved already.

you have to make the index of the row number as follows;
declare a variable int rowVal=0; 

grid.Column(header: "Serial_No", format: item => rowVal = rowVal + 1 + (grid.RowsPerPage * grid.PageIndex)),

 - 

*

> (grid.RowsPerPage * grid.PageIndex) ==>  calculates the offset of the row index of the page number
-----------------------------------

-----------------------------------
```